# Testing connectivity with external services

Tags: java, api, testing, continuous-integration, integration-testing

I'm writting an app that connects with external services (Facebook, Twitter, SMS service ...). Some of them charge money to send and receive messages.

How do I simulate those services for my functional testing? (Don't want to use the real thing, but simulate the protocol). Is there a generic tool for that (preferable opensource/free)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution depends on your product, but generally, if you don't want to actually use those services from your tests you should somehow replicate the response from those services.

For example you can send a test request only once to get a real response from the service and cache the whole response in a format which works for you, then write a simple Mock/Test Wrapper to use this cached response instead of actually communicating with the service.